# IE7 CSS ISSUE works fine in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Please help:
this is my site
http://www.dukeofessexpolocup.com/ when i open in ie7 it doesn't display both left and right ears:

```
div#Ears_left{ padding: 0; float:left; width: 41px;display:inline;}
.custom{margin:0 auto;text-align:center;}
div#Ears_right{ text-align: right;width: 39px;float:right;display:inline;}
div.ears {margin-top: 127px;}
```

Comment: You may want to look at some of the ways your document [doesn't validate](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dukeofessexpolocup.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Not all are necessarily important, but you have some improperly closed tags that may cause issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could look like you're missing a correct closing tag for #Ears_left, as it's rendering outside the  tag when viewed in IE7...

Go over your markup and recheck that you closed your tags correctly.

**UPDATE**

Actually it seems its something inside the div#body that's probably not closed correctly..

As Spudley says in the comment, go here:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dukeofessexpolocup.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=XHTML+1.0+Strict&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2

And start fixing errors :)

Comment: to confirm this (and spot any other errors), I recommend using the W3C validator to check your HTML code.